# double free or corruption error happens when call free in c

Tags: c, free, realloc

I'm a newer in c, for learning it, i'm trying to write a function to manually read characters from std input. The program will read lines from std and output them, ant it will end when meets an empty line.

But it works well if the input stream only contains three lines or lesser, but it always stopped with an error if the input contains 4+ lines. The error happens when call realloc and free function: '**double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001f46030 *****', why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readline(int *length) {
    char ch, *s = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    int UNIT = 3, size = 0, index = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (size == 0 || index >= size) {
            size += UNIT;
            temp = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * size);
            if (s != NULL && temp != s) free(s);
            s = temp;
            temp = NULL;
        }

        s[index++] = (ch == '\n') ? '\0' : ch;
        if (ch == '\n') break;
    }
    *length = index - 1;
    return s;
}

char **readlines(int *count) {
    char **lines = NULL, **tempLines = NULL;
    int UNIT = 1, size = 0, index = 0;
    int length = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    while ((line = readline(&length)) != NULL) {
        if (strlen(line) == 0) break;
        if (size == 0 || index >= size) {
            size += UNIT;
            tempLines = realloc(lines, size * sizeof(char *));
            if (lines != NULL && tempLines != lines) free(lines);
            lines = tempLines;
            tempLines = NULL;
        }
        lines[index++] = line;
    }
    *count = index;
    return lines;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int length = 0, index = 0;
    char **lines = readlines(&length);
    printf("The lines you typed are: \n");
    for (; index < length; index++) {
        printf("%5s %s.\n", "-", lines[index]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The execute result is:

```
xxx@xxx:~/vmshared$ ./mylib2
abc
def
hij

The lines you typed are: 
    - abc.
    - def.
    - hij.
xxx@xxx:~/vmshared$ ./mylib2
11
22
33
44
*** Error in `./mylib2': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000017f1030 ***
```

Comment: Why have you tagged it C++?

Comment: Your code and problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592631/realloc-invalid-next-size-and-malloc-memory-corruption-fast/24592774

Comment: The problem is already addressed in this question: [C - If realloc is used is free necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426700/c-if-realloc-is-used-is-free-necessary)

Comment: regarding the line: if (s != NULL && temp != s) free(s);, the function realloc frees the old area after copying the contents of the old are, unless the returned pointer is the same as the original pointer (it usually but not always changes.)  so your call free( s ) on an area that is already free'd by the realloc function when the new area is not the same as the old area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are freeing your data and then using it:

```
        temp = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * size);
        if (s != NULL && temp != s) free(s);
```

which then means that you are writing to freed memory - which is bad.

The function `realloc` can be seen as doing:

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t new_size)
{
    void* newptr = malloc(size);
    size_t oldsize = find_size(ptr);
    memcpy(newptr, ptr, oldsize);
    free(ptr);
    return newptr;
}
```

Of course, the REAL `realloc` is a lot more complex (because it checks the current block to see if it can be expanded before it allocates new data), and probably doesn't call regular `malloc`, but the functionality is roughly this.

The reason for storing the result of `realloc` in a different variable than the old pointer is for the case where it returns `NULL` - it couldn't expand to the new size - at that point, you need a `temp` and the original pointer, so you don't leak the old pointer's memory.

Answer (score 3):

your problem is here:

```
 temp = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * size);
 if (s != NULL && temp != s) free(s);
```

in case `realloc` succeeded, you free `s` after `realloc` already freed it.
you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5426764/2959585) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

there's a problem with your `readlines` and `readline` function. your error is caused by freeing a pointer after realloc call.

```
tempLines = realloc(lines, size * sizeof(char *));
if (lines != NULL && tempLines != lines) free(lines);  // wrong

temp = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * size);
if (s != NULL && temp != s) free(s);  //wrong
```

if memory content was moved to another location, realloc frees the old pointer for you.
in your main function you never free your `lines` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* free the original memory area after a successful call to realloc.

```
temp = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * size);
if (s != NULL && temp != s) free(s); // This is wrong!
```

If realloc moves your data, it will also free the old area. You don't need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `realloc()` and it is successful, the old memory location has already been freed and the new location is returned.  There is a chance that the old and new locations are the same.  However, either way, it is incorrect to release the old pointer.  It would be eccentric to immediately release the new pointer.

Thus, this code is incorrect:

```
temp = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * size);
if (s != NULL && temp != s)
    free(s);
s = temp;
temp = NULL;
```

It should probably be:

```
temp = realloc(s, size);
if (temp == NULL)
    …report error and exit function…
s = temp;
```

There's no need to set `temp = NULL;` after the assignment, though it does no particular harm beyond marginally (immeasurably) slowing the program down.